# What is difference between Value Log and Audit?

Tags: logging, audit, revision-history

To achieve change tracking in data I serialize object and save it as revision in Value Log table, and for show this changes to end users I prettify and organize value logs to another table as Audit. For old data can I have Audit without Value Log? Or should I do sanitize value log before Audit?Or Can I Remove Value Logs After Auditing them?

Answer (score 0):

The Value Log is the log of the data that persists, but in the Audit, we show when and by who the data changed. It is very based on your implementation to have Value Log or not. If you use event sourcing database or use the built-in change tracking of the DBMS Like SQL SERVER, you can remove the value log table; otherwise, you must have a Value Log table as an intermediate table for the Auditing process. If you have the intermediate table when you want to change an old data, that must be updated too, or ignore the change history and just the sanitize the last version of the data. In this condition, if you have confidence that the Audit Process is reliable you can delete the Value Log Record of the Audited data, but in such condition, we may have inconsistency in data between the main data, ValueLog, And its Audit, So I recommend that don't hard deleting Value Log records and just have a soft delete.